# How to filter data by cell color AND if checkbox value is true in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of games that my friends and I play.

We are trying to find a reliable way of figuring out which games we all want to play.

We have created a **Google Sheet** that lists expected information such as Game Name, a link to the game, number of max players, price, description, game type and finally but most importantly, the traffic light system as to whether or not we want to play it.

**Green** cell color means we want to play it.

**Yellow** cell color means we wouldn't mind giving it a try, or only in certain circumstances (i.e only for a short amount of time).

**Red** cell color means we don't want to play it.

These cell colors are listed against each game, vertically down by each person's name.

**O** in the colored cell indicates that this person already owns that game.

I want to create a filter view (or somehow a saved, accessible filter) that allows me to click on the checkbox of particular people, and then the list is filters by games that are GREEN.

This would mean that I could click the checkbox for Alex and Rach, and then the list would be filtered only by games that Alex and Rach want to BOTH play (as their cell color is green).

How do I go about achieving this?

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: how are those colors assigned?

Comment: @player0 manually but each person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't normally code for you but here's a what you can do using Google Apps Script.

**Try:**

Using Google App Script, use the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();

  var colColors = ss.getRange(4, col, lastRow - 3).getBackgrounds();

  colColors.forEach((color, index) => {
    var row = ss.getRange(index + 4, col)
    
    if (col >= 8 && col <= 12 && e.range.getValue() == true) {
      color == "#00ff00" ? null : ss.hideRow(row);
    } else {
      ss.getRange("H2:L2").uncheck();
      ss.showRows(row.getRow());
    }
  })
};
```

The code uses onEdit Trigger which runs the script everytime you make edits. This then checks if the column you make edits on are on the Columns H-L and then gets the colors of that column which checkbox you checked and filters only those with Green background color.

**Result:**

[image]

The only limitation is it does not reverse the filter so if you uncheck a checkbox it resets all.

Take note also of the color, it is on a hex value. In my test sample the green is equivalent to #00ff00. You might need to change this according to the hex value equivalent to the color green you are using.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly @Dan F Thanks so much!

One small issue was the fact that for big lists, it appears that it struggles to 'unfilter' some of the items towards the bottom of the list but this only happens to 3 or 4 rows so its not an issue. It's also relatively slow to filter but this is also fine.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @JamieBohanna. That's one limitation using the onEdit trigger it really is kind of slow. However it is not possible using a formula/function in sheet since it can't hide rows.